# Will the old_head be updated after the 'do-while'loop and before 'while' loop?

Tags: c++, c++11, concurrency

In 《c++ concurrency in action》page 217,
[image]

Will the old_head be updated after the `do-while` and before `while`?
Then the hazard pointer is set to the wrong old_head?

Comment: I can't see any while loop. You can compile the code and run the program in a debugger to see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two nested loops:

```
node* old_head = head.load();
do {
  node* temp;
  do {
    temp = old_head;
    hp.store(old_head); // write hazard pointer
    old_head = head.load(); // reload head to ensure it has not changed
  } while (old_head != temp); // if head has changed -> retry

// try to remove head
} while (old_head && !head.compare_exchange_strong(old_head, old_head->next));
```

The inner one is used to ensure that the hazard pointer is updated and `old_head` contains a safe reference - that is, the node referenced by `old_head` is protected by the hazard pointer `hp` and can therefore not be reclaimed. We first store `old_head` in `hp`, and then we *reload* `head` to ensure it has not changed. If it has, we have to perform a retry since the node referenced by `old_head` might have been removed already (and therefore potentially released). It is important to note that after this loop `hp` and `old_head` must contain the same value - `hp` is the hazard pointer that protects the node from being released, so if `old_head` were to reference some other node it would not be protected and we could potentially run into a "use after free" scenario.

The outer loop updates `head` to pop the node referenced by `old_head` from the stack. If this `compare_exchange_strong` succeeds, the loop terminates and this thread holds the only *usable* reference to the node. Other threads might be trying to pop the same node, and therefore also hold a reference to it, but they are doomed to fail, because we just updated `head`, so their `compare_exchange_strong` calls can never succeed.

Comment: Thank you.  I misread it.  Another question，the inner `do-while`. We need a temp point. Why?  Is it equal to `do { old_head = head.load(); hp.store(old_head); } while (old_head != head);`?

Comment: Yes, this would be equal, but the version with the temp variable avoids loading `head` twice. In your version you have a load in the comparison (`old_head != head.load()`) and if that fails you restart the loop and load head again (`old_head = head.load()`).